# PCRE: Searching for a string not commented or within a comment block?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm doing a (PCRE) search for strings, but i don't want to match any string that is commented or appears in a comment block, so, in this file:

```
/*
  function someFuncInCommentBlock(){
      return 'match this string';
  }
*/
// var someVarThatsCommented = 'match this string';
var someVar = 'match this string';

function someFunc(){
    return 'match this string';
}
```

... i would only expect to see two matches for `match this string` (the last two that aren't in comments). what sort of pattern syntax do i need do this?

Comment: @vks: _"i would only expect to see two matches for `match this string` (the last two that aren't in comments)"_

Comment: What about stuff like this: `return ' /* match this string */ ';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|//.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'(.*?)'
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/mE6hO4/2)**

[image]

The idea of this regex is match what you don't want and discard it by using flags `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Using this technique commonly named "discard technique" you use a chain of patterns that you want to exclude doing the following:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)     <--- Discard everything block comments
|                                or
//.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)               <--- Discard everything single comments
|                                or
'(.*?)'                          <--- Keep everything withing single quotes
```

In case of PCRE regex you can use the advantage of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to say *exclude everything matching this pattern*.

On the other hand, regex engines that don't support these flags can achieve the same discard technique by using a regex trick that consists of the following OR patterns:

```
exclude this | another pattern to exclude | (save this content)
```

For the regex I posted, if you have to achieve the same in other regex engine you could use this regex:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|//.*|'(.*?)'
```

All the patterns to be excluded are on the left and they are separated by ORs. To the rightest side you have a capturing group that will match what you want. An easy way to see this is using a debuggex graph:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

As **[Bark Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50476/bart-kiers)** pointed in this comment, my regex will match the content within single quotes, it won't explicit match `match this string`. So, in order to match `match this string` you could change the regex to:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|//.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|match this string
```

Comment: Ugh, I was just coming to post my hard work -- #exactlythesame.

Comment: Nice answer! However, if the OP is looking for `match this string` instead of string literals, then this will not work for input `return ' /* match this string */ ';`

Comment: Hi @BartKiers, you are right, don't know what I understood that OP wanted the string within single quotes lol. I'll fix the answer